# INVALID PQ NUMBER-0133

Tags: php, soap, sabre

I get the PNR id and trying to issue the ticket using that pnr. As described in [Sabre Workflow](https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/workflows/Issue_Air_Ticket) I followed the step. As step 1 and step 2 are completed successfully but I stock on step 3 `AirTicketLLSRQ`. I always get the error like :

> INVALID PQ NUMBER-0133

**Request XML :**

```
<AirTicketRQ xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" NumResponses="1" ReturnHostCommand="false" TimeStamp="2016-04-30T06:38:20+00:00" Version="2.7.0">
    <OptionalQualifiers>
        <FlightQualifiers>
            <VendorPrefs>
                <Airline Code="9W" />
            </VendorPrefs>
        </FlightQualifiers>
        <MiscQualifiers>
             <Ticket Type="ETR"/>
        </MiscQualifiers>
        <PricingQualifiers>
            <PriceQuote>
                <NameSelect  NameNumber="1.1"/>
                <Record Number="1" />
            </PriceQuote>
        </PricingQualifiers>
    </OptionalQualifiers>
</AirTicketRQ>
```

**Response :**

```
<AirTicketRS xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:stl="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v01" Version="2.7.0">
            <stl:ApplicationResults status="NotProcessed">
                <stl:Error type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2016-05-25T20:26:57-05:00">
                    <stl:SystemSpecificResults>
                        <stl:Message>INVALID PQ NUMBER-0133</stl:Message>
                        <stl:ShortText>ERR.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE</stl:ShortText>
                    </stl:SystemSpecificResults>
                </stl:Error>
            </stl:ApplicationResults>
        </AirTicketRS>
```

**EnhancedAirBook**

```
<EnhancedAirBookRQ xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/eab/v3_2" version="3.2.0" HaltOnError="true">
    <OTA_AirBookRQ>

        <OriginDestinationInformation>
        <FlightSegment DepartureDateTime="2016-05-29T09:50:00" FlightNumber="263" NumberInParty="1" ResBookDesigCode="V" Status="NN">
             <DestinationLocation LocationCode="DEL" />
             <MarketingAirline Code="9W" FlightNumber="263" />
             <OriginLocation LocationCode="KTM" />
        </FlightSegment></OriginDestinationInformation>
    </OTA_AirBookRQ>

    <OTA_AirPriceRQ>
        <PriceComparison AmountSpecified="13838" /> 

        <PriceRequestInformation  Retain="true">
            <OptionalQualifiers>
                <FlightQualifiers>
                    <VendorPrefs>
                        <Airline Code="9W"/>
                    </VendorPrefs>
                </FlightQualifiers>
            </OptionalQualifiers>
        </PriceRequestInformation>

    </OTA_AirPriceRQ>
    <PostProcessing IgnoreAfter="true">
        <RedisplayReservation/>
    </PostProcessing>
</EnhancedAirBookRQ>
```

**EnhancedAirBookRS**

```
<EnhancedAirBookRS xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/eab/v3_2">
            <ns2:ApplicationResults xmlns:ns2="http://services.sabre.com/STL_Payload/v02_01" status="Complete">
        <ns2:Success timeStamp="2016-05-28T00:15:00.514-05:00"/>
    </ns2:ApplicationResults>
    <OTA_AirBookRS>
        <OriginDestinationOption>
            <FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="05-29T11:20" DepartureDateTime="05-29T09:50" FlightNumber="0263" NumberInParty="001" ResBookDesigCode="V" Status="QF" eTicket="true">
                <DestinationLocation LocationCode="DEL"/>
                <MarketingAirline Code="9W" FlightNumber="0263"/>
                <OriginLocation LocationCode="KTM"/>
            </FlightSegment>
        </OriginDestinationOption>
    </OTA_AirBookRS>
    <OTA_AirPriceRS>
        <PriceComparison AmountReturned="13838" AmountSpecified="13838"/>
        <PriceQuote>
            <MiscInformation>
                <BaggageInfo>
                    <SubCodeProperties MultiTicketSequenceNmbr="1" RPH="1">
                        <AncillaryFeeGroupCode>BG</AncillaryFeeGroupCode>
                        <AncillaryService SubGroupCode="CY">
                            <Text>CARRY ON HAND BAGGAGE</Text>
                        </AncillaryService>
                        <CommercialNameofBaggageItemType>CARRYON HAND BAGGAGE ALLOWANCE</CommercialNameofBaggageItemType>
                        <EMD_Type>4</EMD_Type>
                        <ExtendedSubCodeKey>0LNAB9W</ExtendedSubCodeKey>
                    </SubCodeProperties>
                    <SubCodeProperties MultiTicketSequenceNmbr="1" RPH="2">
                        <AncillaryFeeGroupCode>BG</AncillaryFeeGroupCode>
                        <CommercialNameofBaggageItemType>FREE BAGGAGE ALLOWANCE</CommercialNameofBaggageItemType>
                        <EMD_Type>4</EMD_Type>
                        <ExtendedSubCodeKey>0DFAA9W</ExtendedSubCodeKey>
                    </SubCodeProperties>
                </BaggageInfo>
                <HeaderInformation MultiTicketSequenceNmbr="1">
                    <BargainFinder>
                        <AlternateBooking ResBookDesigCode="3V"/>
                    </BargainFinder>
                    <DepartureDate>2016-05-29</DepartureDate>
                    <Text>VALIDATING CARRIER SPECIFIED - 9W</Text>
                    <Text>BAG ALLOWANCE     -KTMDEL-20KG/9W</Text>
                    <Text>CARRY ON ALLOWANCE</Text>
                    <Text>KTMDEL-01P/9W</Text>
                    <Text>CARRY ON CHARGES</Text>
                    <Text>KTMDEL-9W-CARRY ON FEES UNKNOWN-CONTACT CARRIER</Text>
                    <Text>ADDITIONAL ALLOWANCES AND/OR DISCOUNTS MAY APPLY DEPENDING ON</Text>
                    <Text>FLYER-SPECIFIC FACTORS /E.G. FREQUENT FLYER STATUS/MILITARY/</Text>
                    <Text>CREDIT CARD FORM OF PAYMENT/EARLY PURCHASE OVER INTERNET,ETC./</Text>
                    <ValidatingCarrier Code="9W"/>
                </HeaderInformation>
                <MultiTicketInformation MultiTicketSequenceNmbr="1">
                    <CurrencyCode>NPR</CurrencyCode>
                    <TicketNumber>0</TicketNumber>
                    <TotalAmount>13838</TotalAmount>
                </MultiTicketInformation>
            </MiscInformation>
            <PricedItinerary CurrencyCode="NPR" MultiTicket="false" TotalAmount="13838">
                <AirItineraryPricingInfo MultiTicketSequenceNmbr="1">
                    <AncillaryFees>
                        <FeeInformation>
                            <OB_FeeTicketTotalFareAmount>14237</OB_FeeTicketTotalFareAmount>
                        </FeeInformation>
                    </AncillaryFees>
                    <BaggageProvisions RPH="1">
                        <Associations>
                            <CarrierCode RPH="1">9W</CarrierCode>
                            <CountForSegmentAssociatedID>1</CountForSegmentAssociatedID>
                            <DepartureDate RPH="1">2016-05-29</DepartureDate>
                            <DestinationLocation LocationCode="DEL" RPH="1"/>
                            <FlightNumber RPH="1">263</FlightNumber>
                            <OriginLocation LocationCode="KTM" RPH="1"/>
                            <PNR_Segment RPH="1">4</PNR_Segment>
                            <ResBookDesigCode RPH="1">V</ResBookDesigCode>
                            <StatusCode RPH="1">QF</StatusCode>
                        </Associations>
                        <CarrierWhoseBaggageProvisionsApply>9W</CarrierWhoseBaggageProvisionsApply>
                        <ProvisionType>A</ProvisionType>
                        <SubCodeInfo>
                            <SubCodeForChargesOthers>0DFAA9W</SubCodeForChargesOthers>
                        </SubCodeInfo>
                        <WeightLimit Units="K">20</WeightLimit>
                    </BaggageProvisions>
                    <BaggageProvisions RPH="2">
                        <Associations>
                            <CarrierCode RPH="1">9W</CarrierCode>
                            <CountForSegmentAssociatedID>1</CountForSegmentAssociatedID>
                            <DepartureDate RPH="1">2016-05-29</DepartureDate>
                            <DestinationLocation LocationCode="DEL" RPH="1"/>
                            <FlightNumber RPH="1">263</FlightNumber>
                            <OriginLocation LocationCode="KTM" RPH="1"/>
                            <PNR_Segment RPH="1">4</PNR_Segment>
                            <ResBookDesigCode RPH="1">V</ResBookDesigCode>
                            <StatusCode RPH="1">QF</StatusCode>
                        </Associations>
                        <CarrierWhoseBaggageProvisionsApply>9W</CarrierWhoseBaggageProvisionsApply>
                        <NumPiecesBDI>1</NumPiecesBDI>
                        <ProvisionType>B</ProvisionType>
                        <SubCodeInfo>
                            <SubCodeForChargesOthers>0LNAB9W</SubCodeForChargesOthers>
                        </SubCodeInfo>
                    </BaggageProvisions>
                    <FareCalculation>
                        <Text>KTM 9W DEL Q7.50 52.07NUC59.57END ROE107.38544</Text>
                    </FareCalculation>
                    <FareCalculationBreakdown>
                        <Branch FirstJointCarrier="9W" PCC="3W2D"/>
                        <Departure AirlineCode="9W" AirportCode="KTM" ArrivalAirportCode="DEL" ArrivalCityCode="DEL" CityCode="KTM" GenericInd="O"/>
                        <FareBasis Cabin="Y" Code="V2SPOWNP" FareAmount="52.07" FarePassengerType="ADT" FareType="P" FilingCarrier="9W" GlobalInd="EH" Market="KTMDEL" TripTypeInd="O"/>
                        <FreeBaggageAllowance>KG020</FreeBaggageAllowance>
                        <RuleCategoryIndicator>4</RuleCategoryIndicator>
                        <RuleCategoryIndicator>5</RuleCategoryIndicator>
                        <RuleCategoryIndicator>7</RuleCategoryIndicator>
                        <RuleCategoryIndicator>8</RuleCategoryIndicator>
                        <RuleCategoryIndicator>9</RuleCategoryIndicator>
                        <RuleCategoryIndicator>10</RuleCategoryIndicator>
                        <RuleCategoryIndicator>12</RuleCategoryIndicator>
                        <RuleCategoryIndicator>15</RuleCategoryIndicator>
                        <RuleCategoryIndicator>16</RuleCategoryIndicator>
                        <RuleCategoryIndicator>18</RuleCategoryIndicator>
                        <Surcharges Ind="Q" Type="UNK">7.50</Surcharges>
                    </FareCalculationBreakdown>
                    <ItinTotalFare NonRefundableInd="O">
                        <BaggageInfo>
                            <NonUS_DOT_Disclosure>
                                <Text>BAG ALLOWANCE     -KTMDEL-20KG/9W</Text>
                                <Text>CARRY ON ALLOWANCE</Text>
                                <Text>KTMDEL-01P/9W</Text>
                                <Text>CARRY ON CHARGES</Text>
                                <Text>KTMDEL-9W-CARRY ON FEES UNKNOWN-CONTACT CARRIER</Text>
                                <Text>ADDITIONAL ALLOWANCES AND/OR DISCOUNTS MAY APPLY DEPENDING ON</Text>
                                <Text>FLYER-SPECIFIC FACTORS /E.G. FREQUENT FLYER STATUS/MILITARY/</Text>
                                <Text>CREDIT CARD FORM OF PAYMENT/EARLY PURCHASE OVER INTERNET,ETC./</Text>
                            </NonUS_DOT_Disclosure>
                        </BaggageInfo>
                        <BaseFare Amount="6397" CurrencyCode="NPR"/>
                        <Endorsements>
                            <Text>NON ENDO</Text>
                        </Endorsements>
                        <Taxes TotalAmount="7441">
                            <Tax Amount="3382" TaxCode="YQF" TaxName="SERVICE FEE - FUEL" TicketingTaxCode="YQ"/>
                            <Tax Amount="1130" TaxCode="NQ" TaxName="TOURISM SERVICE FEE" TicketingTaxCode="NQ"/>
                            <Tax Amount="791" TaxCode="NP1" TaxName="PASSENGER SERVICE CHARGE" TicketingTaxCode="NP"/>
                            <Tax Amount="1000" TaxCode="B6" TaxName="AIRPORT DEVELOPMENT FEE" TicketingTaxCode="B6"/>
                            <Tax Amount="1138" TaxCode="IN2" TaxName="USER DEVELOPMENT FEE INTL ARRI" TicketingTaxCode="IN"/>
                        </Taxes>
                        <TotalFare Amount="13838" CurrencyCode="NPR"/>
                    </ItinTotalFare>
                    <PassengerTypeQuantity Code="ADT" Quantity="1"/>
                    <PTC_FareBreakdown>
                        <Cabin>Y</Cabin>
                        <FareBasis Code="V2SPOWNP" FareAmount="52.07" FarePassengerType="ADT" FareType="P" FilingCarrier="9W" GlobalInd="EH" Market="KTMDEL"/>
                        <FreeBaggageAllowance>KG020</FreeBaggageAllowance>
                        <Surcharges Ind="Q" Type="UNK">7.50</Surcharges>
                    </PTC_FareBreakdown>
                    <TicketingFees>
                        <FeeInformation Amount="399" FunctionCode="FCA" ServiceType="OB"/>
                    </TicketingFees>
                </AirItineraryPricingInfo>
            </PricedItinerary>
        </PriceQuote>
    </OTA_AirPriceRS>
    <TravelItineraryReadRS>
        <TravelItinerary>
            <CustomerInfo>
                <Address>
                    <AddressLine>TARA TRAVEL</AddressLine>
                    <AddressLine>3150 DDDD DRIVE</AddressLine>
                    <AddressLine>KTM, KTM NP</AddressLine>
                    <AddressLine>977</AddressLine>
                </Address>
                <ContactNumbers>
                    <ContactNumber LocationCode="KTM" Phone="9846231634-A-1.1" RPH="001"/>
                    <ContactNumber LocationCode="KTM" Phone="9846231634-A-1.1" RPH="002"/>
                </ContactNumbers>
                <PersonName NameNumber="01.01" PassengerType="ADT" RPH="1" WithInfant="false">
                    <Email>SUBEDIKIRAN41@GMAIL.COM1.1</Email>
                    <Email>SUBEDIKIRAN41@GMAIL.COM1.1</Email>
                    <GivenName>HELLO</GivenName>
                    <Surname>SUBEDI</Surname>
                </PersonName>
                <PersonName NameNumber="02.01" PassengerType="ADT" RPH="2" WithInfant="false">
                    <Email>SUBEDIKIRAN41@GMAIL.COM1.1</Email>
                    <Email>SUBEDIKIRAN41@GMAIL.COM1.1</Email>
                    <GivenName>HELLO</GivenName>
                    <Surname>SUBEDI</Surname>
                </PersonName>
            </CustomerInfo>
            <ItineraryInfo>
                <ItineraryPricing>
                    <PriceQuote RPH="1">
                        <MiscInformation>
                            <SignatureLine ExpirationDateTime="00:00" Source="SYS" Status="EXPIRED">
                                <Text>3W2D 3W2D*ATH 1044/28MAY16</Text>
                            </SignatureLine>
                            <TicketingFees Disclaimer="ONE OR MORE FORM OF PAYMENT FEES MAY APPLY"/>
                            <TicketingFees Disclaimer="ACTUAL TOTAL WILL BE BASED ON FORM OF PAYMENT USED"/>
                            <TicketingFees Disclaimer="FEE CODE     DESCRIPTION                         FEE">
                                <FeeInformation Amount="399" FunctionCode="FCA" ServiceType="OB">- ANY CC</FeeInformation>
                            </TicketingFees>
                        </MiscInformation>
                        <PricedItinerary DisplayOnly="false" InputMessage="WPA9WRQ" RPH="1" StatusCode="A" TaxExempt="false" ValidatingCarrier="9W">
                            <AirItineraryPricingInfo>
                                <ItinTotalFare>
                                    <BaseFare Amount="6397" CurrencyCode="NPR"/>
                                    <Taxes>
                                        <Tax Amount="7441" TaxCode="XT"/>
                                        <TaxBreakdownCode TaxPaid="false">1130NQ</TaxBreakdownCode>
                                        <TaxBreakdownCode TaxPaid="false">791NP</TaxBreakdownCode>
                                        <TaxBreakdownCode TaxPaid="false">1000B6</TaxBreakdownCode>
                                        <TaxBreakdownCode TaxPaid="false">1138IN</TaxBreakdownCode>
                                        <TaxBreakdownCode TaxPaid="false">3382YQ</TaxBreakdownCode>
                                    </Taxes>
                                    <TotalFare Amount="13838" CurrencyCode="NPR"/>
                                    <Totals>
                                        <BaseFare Amount="12794"/>
                                        <Taxes>
                                            <Tax Amount="14882"/>
                                        </Taxes>
                                        <TotalFare Amount="27676"/>
                                    </Totals>
                                </ItinTotalFare>
                                <PassengerTypeQuantity Code="ADT" Quantity="02"/>
                                <PTC_FareBreakdown>
                                    <Endorsements>
                                        <Endorsement type="SYSTEM_ENDORSEMENT">
                                            <Text>NON ENDO</Text>
                                        </Endorsement>
                                        <Endorsement type="PRICING_PARAMETER">
                                            <Text>WPA9W$RQ</Text>
                                        </Endorsement>
                                        <Endorsement type="WARNING">
                                            <Text>VALIDATING CARRIER SPECIFIED - 9W</Text>
                                        </Endorsement>
                                    </Endorsements>
                                    <FareBasis Code="V2SPOWNP"/>
                                    <FareCalculation>
                                        <Text>KTM 9W DEL Q7.50 52.07NUC59.57END ROE107.38544</Text>
                                    </FareCalculation>
                                    <FareSource>ATPC</FareSource>
                                    <FlightSegment ConnectionInd="O" DepartureDateTime="05-29T09:50" FlightNumber="263" ResBookDesigCode="V" SegmentNumber="3" Status="OK">
                                        <BaggageAllowance Number="20K"/>
                                        <FareBasis Code="V2SPOWNP"/>
                                        <MarketingAirline Code="9W" FlightNumber="263"/>
                                        <OriginLocation LocationCode="KTM"/>
                                        <ValidityDates>
                                            <NotValidAfter>2016-05-29</NotValidAfter>
                                            <NotValidBefore>2016-05-29</NotValidBefore>
                                        </ValidityDates>
                                    </FlightSegment>
                                    <FlightSegment>
                                        <OriginLocation LocationCode="DEL"/>
                                    </FlightSegment>
                                </PTC_FareBreakdown>
                            </AirItineraryPricingInfo>
                        </PricedItinerary>
                        <ResponseHeader>
                            <Text>FARE - PRICE RETAINED</Text>
                            <Text>FARE USED TO CALCULATE DISCOUNT</Text>
                            <Text>FARE NOT GUARANTEED UNTIL TICKETED</Text>
                        </ResponseHeader>
                        <PriceQuotePlus DiscountAmount="0" DisplayOnly="false" DomesticIntlInd="I" IT_BT_Fare="BT" ItineraryChanged="false" ManualFare="false" NUCSuppresion="false" NegotiatedFare="false" PricingStatus="A" SubjToGovtApproval="false" SystemIndicator="S" VerifyFareCalc="false">
                            <PassengerInfo>
                                <PassengerData NameNumber="01.01">SUBEDI/HELLO</PassengerData>
                                <PassengerData NameNumber="02.01">SUBEDI/HELLO</PassengerData>
                            </PassengerInfo>
                            <TicketingInstructionsInfo/>
                        </PriceQuotePlus>
                    </PriceQuote>
                    <PriceQuoteTotals>
                        <BaseFare Amount="12794.00"/>
                        <Taxes>
                            <Tax Amount="14882.00"/>
                        </Taxes>
                        <TotalFare Amount="27676.00"/>
                    </PriceQuoteTotals>
                </ItineraryPricing>
                <ReservationItems>
                    <Item RPH="1">
                        <MiscSegment DayOfWeekInd="7" DepartureDateTime="05-29" NumberInParty="01" SegmentNumber="0001" Status="PN" Type="PTA">
                            <OriginLocation LocationCode="KTM"/>
                            <Text>RETENTION SEGMENT</Text>
                            <Vendor Code="9W"/>
                        </MiscSegment>
                    </Item>
                    <Item RPH="2">
                        <MiscSegment DayOfWeekInd="7" DepartureDateTime="05-29" NumberInParty="01" SegmentNumber="0002" Status="NN" Type="PTA">
                            <OriginLocation LocationCode="KTM"/>
                            <Text>RETENTION SEGMENT</Text>
                            <Vendor Code="9W"/>
                        </MiscSegment>
                    </Item>
                    <Item RPH="3">
                        <FlightSegment AirMilesFlown="0507" ArrivalDateTime="05-29T11:20" DayOfWeekInd="7" DepartureDateTime="2016-05-29T09:50" ElapsedTime="01.45" FlightNumber="0263" NumberInParty="01" ResBookDesigCode="V" SegmentNumber="0003" SmokingAllowed="false" SpecialMeal="false" Status="QF" StopQuantity="00" eTicket="true">
                            <DestinationLocation LocationCode="DEL" Terminal="TERMINAL 3" TerminalCode="3"/>
                            <Equipment AirEquipType="738"/>
                            <MarketingAirline Code="9W" FlightNumber="0263"/>
                            <Meal Code="B"/>
                            <OriginLocation LocationCode="KTM"/>
                            <UpdatedArrivalTime>05-29T11:20</UpdatedArrivalTime>
                            <UpdatedDepartureTime>05-29T09:50</UpdatedDepartureTime>
                        </FlightSegment>
                    </Item>
                </ReservationItems>
                <Ticketing RPH="01" TicketTimeLimit="T-"/>
            </ItineraryInfo>
            <ItineraryRef AirExtras="false" ID="SLWRRW" InhibitCode="U" PartitionID="AA" PrimeHostID="1B">
                <Header>PRICE QUOTE RECORD - AUTOPRICED</Header>
                <Source AAA_PseudoCityCode="3W2D" CreateDateTime="2016-05-28T00:05" CreationAgent="ATH" HomePseudoCityCode="3W2D" LastUpdateDateTime="2016-05-28T00:05" PseudoCityCode="3W2D" ReceivedFrom="TESTING" SequenceNumber="1"/>
            </ItineraryRef>
        </TravelItinerary>
    </TravelItineraryReadRS>
</EnhancedAirBookRS>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't store the fare yet, you could do it using OTA_AirPriceRQ, specifying this tag: PriceRetention, property: Default="true".

That will create PQ.

Answer (score 0):

Have you stored a fare yet? If any PQ exists in the PNR it should default to PQ record number 1, so it sounds like there is may not be a pricing record present at the time you are sending the ticketing request.

Comment: Yes, I haven't send any pricing record yet. In which process( `EnhancedAirBookRQ` or `PassengerDetailsRQ` ) I should send the pricing recode ? Is it necessary to send the PQ record ??

Comment: I'm not that familiar wth those APIs but you've definitely got to store a fare before ticketing.

Comment: Yes, I have stored the details and send the price info in `EnhancedAirBookRQ` but I get the same error in  `AirTicketLLSRQ` .

Comment: Can you share your EnhancedAirBook request and the response you get?
That way we can see if the price quote got stored in the PNR, prior to your AirTicketLLSRQ call.

Comment: Ok, now I had edit my question. Check the EnhancedAirBook request and response from above

Answer (score 0):

It seems the price quote is being stored, and the ticketing parameters look correct.

I'm wondering if the way you are implementing the workflow (EnhancedAirBook/PostProcessing/@IgnoreAfter=true) is removing the PNR from the session working area, and then you are trying to issue a ticket (calling AirTicketRQ) without a PNR on the session.
Can you try setting IgnoreAfter=false?

Also, I'm assuming you are calling PassengerDetails on your workflow in order to finish up the PNR before ticketing?

Finally, depending on your PCC configuration, the form of payment (AirTicketRQ/OptionalQualifiers/FOP_Qualifiers) maybe required.

The sample workflow provided for Air Ticketing under: https://github.com/SabreDevStudio/SabreAPIsWorkflows - has an example using Cash as form of payment, for testing purposes.